# How can I pass Angular directives, so they operate on child components

Tags: angular, angular-material

Suppose I have an angular component...

```
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

And this component is implemented such that it contains a native input field (not via transclusion) ...

```
<MyComponent>
    <input>
</MyComponent>
```

And I want to apply a directive to MyComponent, so that it really applies to the internal component. For example:

```
<MyComponent mat-input></MyComponent>
```

I want the matInput directive to really be applied to the child component.

How can this be done?

Can I expose the internal component as the outer component?
Can I implement some method on MyComponent, so that directive are applied to an internal component?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have few ways to pass data to the component. But in all of them you have to prepare the internals you want pass. Like this:

In your component MyComponent `html`:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

And in the usage place you define the passed element:

```
<app-my-component>
  <input matInput>
</app-my-component>
```

--

Another way is to define the `template` with your data:

```
<ng-template #someTemplate>
  <input matInput>
</ng-template>
```

And then you can save this `template` and operate as variable. For example pass to your `MyComponent` and render with:

```
<ng-template 
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate(..here you should return someTemplate)">
</ng-template>
```